# Auto insert semicolon after class definition in Codelite

Tags: c++, class, codelite

When writing classes in Codelite, I get this annoying behaviour where the IDE doesn't insert a semicolon after the closing brace, which has resulted in a few annoying syntax errors when compiling.
I tried looking in the program's Preferences menu but couldn't find a relevant option and Google didn't help either in this respect.
Is there any option at all to enable the auto-insertion of a semicolon after a class declaration?

Comment: There's no requirement to end a class definition with a semi-colon, for instance `class X { } x, y, z;` is perfectly legal code.

Comment: It likely depends on with what wizard/plugin you generate these classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeLite does not do that by default and there is no setting that you can modify to do that.

You can however, achieve this in two other ways:

**Use the class wizard:**

Create your class using the 'Class Wizard': Right click on a folder in the tree view and select `New class`

**Use the abbreviations plugin**

- From the menu bar: `plugins->abbreviations->settings`
- Click on the new entry button (green plus icon)
- Name it "class" (or a name of your choice) and paste the following code:

  class | {
  public:

  };
- Click "Save"
- Now when typing in the editor `class` hit: `Ctrl-ENTER` and you will see this entry - select it and it will added to the text editor for you.

NOTE: the `|` marker indicates where CodeLite will place the caret, You can have multiple carets. So the above example can be expanded to something like this:

```
class | {
public:
    |(){}
    ~|(){}
};
```

Now, when CodeLite adds this snippet to the editor, you will get 3 carets. Typing the class name will add them in all three locations

NOTE 2: The above was tested using CodeLite 11.0.8 (git latest), but it should work with CodeLite 11.0 as well

HTH,

Eran, Author of CodeLite IDE